# WDS OS DEPLOYMENT WINDOWS 11

Tags: wds, mdt

I am trying to deploy windows 10 or 11 through MDT/WDS.
Now I have done all the steps needed, the problem is
When I create a vm in hyper v gen 1 everything is running fine as soon as I would like it to run in gen 2 am getting the following ERROR attached is a screenshots.
I set up the dhcp with options 66 and 67 the pxe is working it loads the wim and starts to run but shortly after it starts it stops and few seconds later it gets that message attached.
Any ideas here why this is happening?.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUheF.jpg)

Comment: Your post isn’t clear. You can’t change a VM from Gen 1 to Gen 2 without reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert from a Gen 1 VM to a Gen 2 VM while still retaining a supported configuration.

MS's official stance is that you have to rebuild the VM from scratch.
This is because the Gen 1 VM uses BIOS to boot and Gen 2 uses UEFI to boot and the requirements change greatly. E.g. Disk partitioning layout needs to change from MBR to GPT, HAL needs rebuilt, etc...
Microsoft also is dropping support from deploying images from WDS, you can now only PXE boot Windows PE images from it.
MDT is still supported but on its last legs.

Thanks!